# Rust не определяет T как наследника Futures внутри имплиментации трейта

Tags: rust

Пробую неспешно вникать в раст и читаю примеры tokio (https://tokio.rs/docs/futures/basic/). К сожалению, примеры там для более старой версии futures, чем 0.3, поэтому приходится их ещё и переписывать. В процессе столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

```
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tokio::prelude::*;
use futures::Future;
use futures::task::Poll;
use futures::stream::StreamExt;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::Context;
use std::fmt;


struct HelloWorld;

impl Future for HelloWorld {
    type Output = String;

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        Poll::Ready("hello world".to_string())
    }
}


struct Display<T>(T);

impl<T> Future for Display<T>
where
    T: Future,
{
    type Output = ();
    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<()> {
        let value = match self.0.poll(cx) {
            Poll::Ready(value) => value,
            Poll::Pending => return Poll::Pending,
        };

        println!("{}", value);
        Poll::Ready(())
    }
}
```

Но получаю следующую ошибку:

> no method named `poll` found for type `T` in the current scope method
>   not found in `T` help: items from traits can only be used if the type
>   parameter is bounded by the traitrustc(E0599) main.rs(30, 34): method
>   not found in `T`

Вот в этой строке: `let value = match self.0.poll(cx) {`

Не могу понять, почему Rust не определяет T как наследника Futures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Сам в раст захожу только постольку-поскольку.)

Вы наткнулись на один из примеров ужасных сообщений об ошибках, которые,
по моему опыту, выдаёт компилятор каждый раз, когда начинается что-то
более-менее сложное.  Что он вам на самом деле хочет сказать, что вам
надо повозиться с `Pin`ами и другими трейтами.  Минимальный
код:

```rust
use std::fmt;
use std::future;
use std::marker;
use std::pin;
use std::task;

struct Display<T>(T);

impl<T, O> future::Future for Display<T>
where
    T: future::Future<Output = O> + marker::Unpin,
    O: fmt::Display,
{
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(mut self: pin::Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut task::Context<'_>) -> task::Poll<()> {
        let value = match pin::Pin::new(&mut self.0).poll(cx) {
            task::Poll::Ready(value) => value,
            task::Poll::Pending => return task::Poll::Pending,
        };

        println!("{}", value);

        task::Poll::Ready(())
    }
}

fn main() {}
```